# Static background w/ objects in openGL. Best way to "bake"?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, scene

I'm making a 2D game in openGL and I have a list of static objects. Thus far I'm looping through them and drawing them into the room, however in some large rooms there are up to 2000 of them and speed is critical so I'd like to find a way to "bake" them all together and never update them in the draw loop after that.

How can I do this and what's the best way in terms of performance, memory usage, gpu ram usage etc?

I'd prefer to use oGL 2, but I'm considering oGL 3+.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 2D? Is the gameplay constrained to two dimensions but using 3D models or are you doing a classic sprite based 2D game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to move all the data of those objects to the GPU so that rendering commands will fetch memory directly from GPU memory. It can be done by simply using VBO or even DisplayList (in 'old' OpenGL 2.0 and before).

Probably the DisplayList solution wll be the most efficient because you can 'pack' all the commands inside... with VBO you can pack only the geometry data, the materials need to be setup every frame.
Related topic: instacing (but you will have to use GL 3+).

Another way is to render them to textures... and display them as simple Sprits. This technique is called 'impostors', here is some info:  [True Impostors](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch21.html).

Another option: render the environment to a Cube Map. It could work for objects that are far away from the camera (like hills, tries, etc...) but in a room it could look strange.

Answer (score 0):

First option: make single mesh for objects. For example, you may dynamically update index array with objects that are visible. Very important in this case that textures you use should be in an *atlas*. If you can't share shader and textures there is no much effect from this technique. You may combine this method, grouping by material an texture and using single draw call to render. For example, first draw call - render 100 trees with one texture, and than render 600 apples on them and after 100 clouds.

Another option, if your objects are static you may render all of them into texture using FBO. This may be applied if your objects like background. For example, your render random stars (1000) in space for your galaxy.